# Google ads are not showing in a particular app

Tags: ios, admob, ads

I am getting the following error when loading an interstitial in an iOS app:

> Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: No ad to show.}

I have tried with various live AD IDs, but the ad never shows. However, if I use a test AD ID, the ad shows.

If I use the live AD IDs in other apps, the ads show. It seems that the problem is with the particular app when using live AD IDs.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Mainly there are 2 types of Google Ads, Banner ads and Interstitial ads. Banner ads are received as a complete view from the Google API's, whereas for interstitial ads you only get the params that you can display on your custom UI.

For live Ad ID's to work, you need to get your App whitelisted by Google. Since you are able to use the test Ad ID's and not the live Ad ID's, your app might not have been whitelisted yet. After your app gets whitelisted you should be able to receive the ads from Google Ads.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Krishna's answer: the issue may be simply that there are no ads to show. Google tries to pick an ad based on targeting parameters that you pass in (e.g. location), user's AdID (a unique ad-specific identifier used for targeting) and your AdUnitID settings (on the server side) and other things (device type, possibly IP address, current time, etc.). Sometimes it just can't find a suitable ad.

In test mode you always get an ad (for testing purposes). But, of course, I'd recommend exploring the "whitelisting" first.